# javascript fetch does not catch 404 error

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, fetch

I have an app with uses a fetch to retrieve information from a 3rd party API.  I am calling the API via cors-anywhere-herokuapp.com.  When I call the API with valid data, I am able to retrieve the API response and pick up the data I need to pick up.  When I call the API with invalid data, the API returns a 404 server error.  I am forcing invalid data so I can code to catch this situation.  My problem appears to be that the fetch does not catch the 404 error.  I have tried coding to inspect the return.status but to no avail. I tried testing return.ok and that didn't work either.  This is the code I am executing:

```
            function showProduct(barcode) {

            let url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=" + barcode + "&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaia85n9dk2d4i";

            url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459211&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaia85n9dk2d4i";

            const options = { method: 'GET' };                
            fetch( url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                if (myJson == undefined) 
                {
                    console.log("fetch failed")
                } 
                else 
                {     
                    //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
                    document.getElementById("showScanner").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("scanner-container").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("showProductDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("productManufacturer").innerHTML = myJson.products[0].manufacturer;
                    document.getElementById("productName").innerHTML = myJson.products[0].product_name;
                    document.getElementById("productDescription").innerHTML = myJson.products[0].description;          
                    Quagga.stop(); 
                    }
            });
        }
```

and this is what I see in the debugger when I execute the code

[image]

When I look at the debugger network tab, and click on Headers, I see this:
[image]

So, my question is, how do I capture the status code?

Comment: `.then(function(response) {` in here, `response.status` will be 404 - it's up to you to decide how to react to that

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation on fetch's response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), you should be able to testthe status code of the response that `fetch`'s Promise resolves to using `response.status`.

Note that although it's unintuitive, the Promise `fetch` returns only rejects when there's a connection error.  If the connection succeeds and there's a response, this promise will resolve with the response, even if the status code is non-200.